C header file /linux/if_arp.h has errors
When I compile my program it gives me errors for <linux/if_arp.h>. it keeps on giving me errors for re-declarations. I want to release my program soon , and I am not sure what I can do about this problems. This sentence is just filler so I can post this question because It keeps giving me the It "looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" error, and I feel like I've added enough
In file included from /usr/include/linux/netdevice.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/linux/if_arp.h:27,
                 from rcping.c:6:
/usr/include/net/if.h:44:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_UP'
   44 |     IFF_UP = 0x1,               /* Interface is up.  */
      |     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:83:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_UP' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   83 |         IFF_UP                          = 1<<0,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:46:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_BROADCAST'
   46 |     IFF_BROADCAST = 0x2,        /* Broadcast address valid.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:84:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_BROADCAST' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   84 |         IFF_BROADCAST                   = 1<<1,  /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:48:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_DEBUG'
   48 |     IFF_DEBUG = 0x4,            /* Turn on debugging.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:85:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_DEBUG' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   85 |         IFF_DEBUG                       = 1<<2,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:50:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_LOOPBACK'
   50 |     IFF_LOOPBACK = 0x8,         /* Is a loopback net.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:86:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_LOOPBACK' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   86 |         IFF_LOOPBACK                    = 1<<3,  /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:52:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_POINTOPOINT'
   52 |     IFF_POINTOPOINT = 0x10,     /* Interface is point-to-point link.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:87:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_POINTOPOINT' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   87 |         IFF_POINTOPOINT                 = 1<<4,  /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:54:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_NOTRAILERS'
   54 |     IFF_NOTRAILERS = 0x20,      /* Avoid use of trailers.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:88:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_NOTRAILERS' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   88 |         IFF_NOTRAILERS                  = 1<<5,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:56:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_RUNNING'
   56 |     IFF_RUNNING = 0x40,         /* Resources allocated.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:89:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_RUNNING' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   89 |         IFF_RUNNING                     = 1<<6,  /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:58:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_NOARP'
   58 |     IFF_NOARP = 0x80,           /* No address resolution protocol.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:90:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_NOARP' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   90 |         IFF_NOARP                       = 1<<7,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:60:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_PROMISC'
   60 |     IFF_PROMISC = 0x100,        /* Receive all packets.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:91:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_PROMISC' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   91 |         IFF_PROMISC                     = 1<<8,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:64:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_ALLMULTI'
   64 |     IFF_ALLMULTI = 0x200,       /* Receive all multicast packets.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:92:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_ALLMULTI' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   92 |         IFF_ALLMULTI                    = 1<<9,  /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:67:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_MASTER'
   67 |     IFF_MASTER = 0x400,         /* Master of a load balancer.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:93:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_MASTER' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   93 |         IFF_MASTER                      = 1<<10, /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:69:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_SLAVE'
   69 |     IFF_SLAVE = 0x800,          /* Slave of a load balancer.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:94:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_SLAVE' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   94 |         IFF_SLAVE                       = 1<<11, /* __volatile__ */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:72:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_MULTICAST'
   72 |     IFF_MULTICAST = 0x1000,     /* Supports multicast.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:95:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_MULTICAST' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   95 |         IFF_MULTICAST                   = 1<<12, /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:75:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_PORTSEL'
   75 |     IFF_PORTSEL = 0x2000,       /* Can set media type.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:96:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_PORTSEL' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   96 |         IFF_PORTSEL                     = 1<<13, /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:77:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_AUTOMEDIA'
   77 |     IFF_AUTOMEDIA = 0x4000,     /* Auto media select active.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:97:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_AUTOMEDIA' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   97 |         IFF_AUTOMEDIA                   = 1<<14, /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:79:5: error: redeclaration of enumerator 'IFF_DYNAMIC'
   79 |     IFF_DYNAMIC = 0x8000        /* Dialup device with changing addresses.  */
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:98:9: note: previous definition of 'IFF_DYNAMIC' with type 'enum net_device_flags'
   98 |         IFF_DYNAMIC                     = 1<<15, /* sysfs */
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from rcping.c:7:
/usr/include/net/if.h:111:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifmap'
  111 | struct ifmap
      |        ^~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:194:8: note: originally defined here
  194 | struct ifmap {
      |        ^~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:126:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifreq'
  126 | struct ifreq
      |        ^~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:232:8: note: originally defined here
  232 | struct ifreq {
      |        ^~~~~
/usr/include/net/if.h:176:8: error: redefinition of 'struct ifconf'
  176 | struct ifconf
      |        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/linux/if.h:284:8: note: originally defined here
  284 | struct ifconf  {

code I am compiling
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <libcap.h>
#include <string.h>
#define RCP 49152
#define sizepkt 512
struct RCP_packet {
uint16_t srcport;
uint16_t extport;
char* payload;
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
int intextport = atoi(argv[1]);
    cap_t caps = cap_init();
        cap_value_t *capvl = 0;
            cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_NET_RAW, 1, capvl, CAP_SET);
int sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, RCP);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    printf("Socket not created\n");
    printf("%d\n", sockfd);
    return -1;
    } else {
        printf("Socket Created successfully\n");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in *dst_addr;
    char buffer[sizepkt];
        dst_addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
        dst_addr->sin_port = htons(intextport);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &dst_addr->sin_addr);
        struct sockaddr_ll *src_addr;
        src_addr->sll_family = AF_PACKET;
        src_addr->sll_protocol = htons(1560);
        src_addr->sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("wlan0");
        struct sockaddr *addr = (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr;
        struct sockaddr *interlcal = (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr;
     struct RCP_packet *packet;
     packet->srcport = htons(49152);
     packet->extport = htons(intextport);
     strcpy(packet->payload, "This packet was sent using RCPing under the Really Crappy Protocol");
        memcpy(buffer, &packet->srcport, sizeof(packet->srcport));
            memcpy(buffer + sizeof(packet->srcport), &packet->extport, sizeof(packet->extport));
                memcpy(buffer + sizeof(packet->srcport) + sizeof(packet->extport), packet->payload, 8);
                   struct RCP_packet *rcp;
        rcp->srcport = htons(1560);
        rcp->extport = htons(intextport);
        int miku = bind(sockfd, interlcal, sizeof(interlcal));
        if (miku < 0) {
            printf("Local interface couldn't be set up\n");
            printf("%d", miku);
            return -1;
        }

        int jumanji = connect(sockfd, addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (jumanji < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't establish a connection using RCP, unsurprisingly\n");
        printf("%d", jumanji);
        return -1;
    } else {
        while (main) {
            ssize_t senresult = send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if (senresult < 0) {
                printf("Package wasn't sent");
            }
        }
    }
}


Please include the code that you're compiling.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the About page soon and also visit the links describing How to Ask a Question and How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example. Providing the necessary details will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

how are you compiling the program? add the compile command you're using to the question

This appears to be some internal libc crap which defines said enum based on __UAPI_DEF_IF_NET_DEVICE_FLAGS in libc-compat.h. This is where one starts to randomly reinstall all the things and hope for the best.

This is happening because there are two sets of networking headers in the system: one under /usr/include/linux and another under /usr/include/net. The headers are effectively identical, but their include guards define different preprocessor symbols. #include <linux/if_arp.h> refers to the former while #include <net/if.h> refers to the latter.
The difference between the two sets of headers is explored in the answers to this question.
The problem should be resolved with the following change to your includes:
// #include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <net/if_arp.h>

